# How add Service Reference to a WCF Service in Android project

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, wcf, xamarin

I am developping an Android app in Xamarin (so c#) which have to connect a Sqlite Database. For that i created a WCF Application (which will be hosted on a vps later) for make SQL requests and return results to my app. But when i wanted to add the service reference to my Android projet, i just couldn't... There is only Add -> Web reference, but no Add -> Service reference as in other project templates like Console app.. 
So my question: how can i use my WCF Service in my Android app? Or there is other solutions to use a online database? Thanks

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/

Comment: Ok i'll try this, so there is no way to add a service just with Add menu for Android or iOs project like in other ones?